# how can my sql script determine whether it is running in sqldeveloper or sqlplus?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to work around the SQLDeveloper linesize bug by writing my script to detect whether it's SQL*Plus or SQLDeveloper.  Something like:

```
COLUMN SET_THE_LINE new_value TARGETLINESIZE noprint
SELECT DECODE ('&&_SQLPLUS_RELEASE.','',5,500) as SET_THE_LINE from dual;
SET LINESIZE &&TARGETLINESIZE
```

I know that SQL*Plus always sets the value of _SQLPLUS_RELEASE and, understandably, SQLDeveloper does not.

Unfortunately SQLDeveloper always prompts for the value of _SQLPLUS_RELEASE.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with an SQL Developer linesize bug, so not sure what the end result is supposed to be. But you can use [`sys_context`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/functions184.htm) for this:

```
select sys_context('USERENV', 'MODULE') from dual;
```

Which gives:

```
SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','MODULE')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL*Plus
```

... or:

```
SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','MODULE')                                           
-------------------------------
SQL Developer
```

So you can adapt what you have as:

```
column set_the_line new_value targetlinesize noprint
set termout off
select case sys_context('USERENV', 'MODULE')
    when 'SQL Developer' then 5 else 500 end as set_the_line from dual;
set termout on
set linesize &&targetlinesize
```

And then test with

```
show linesize
```

which gives `linesize 500` in SQL*Plus and `linesize 5` in SQL Developer.

---

If you might not be connected yet in SQL*Plus, just define the value first; you don't even need to do anything special to hide the error from the `select` beyond the `set termout off`, though you could include a `whenever sqlerror` just in case your `login.sql` is setting it to exit - but then you maybe have to know to reset it afterwards.

```
define targetlinesize=500
whenever sqlerror continue
set termout off
column set_the_line new_value targetlinesize noprint
select case sys_context('USERENV', 'MODULE')
    when 'SQL Developer' then 5 else 500 end as set_the_line from dual;
set termout on
set linesize &&targetlinesize
show linesize
```

The `column` value will override it if the select succeeds, and not touch it if it fails. If I put that in a file called `client.sql` and run it as:

```
sqlplus -s /nolog @client
```

I only get this output:

```
linesize 500
```

And the same thing runs in SQL Developer, giving `linesize 5` again.

Comment: Close, but - gaaaaa! I have a scripting protocol in which my script starts out NOT connected to a database.  Hmmmmm...   when I run through sqldeveloper, I AM connected, so this WOULD work...   But then I need to shut the silly thing up in SQLplus when it starts out NOT connected.......    Thank you, Alex, you've stirred my little gray cells!

Comment: And the example I gave used a SELECT too... I'm marking yours as the solution.  Thanks again!

Comment: @AndrewWolfe - you've probably got this sorted out by now, but I've added a tweak so it works if you aren't conected yet.

Answer (score 3):

You can query the executable name from v$session

```
select program from v$session where sid = sys_context('userenv','sid')
```

sql*plus for example will be `sqlplus.exe`.

@alex's way is also good but module is easily manipulated and often used by application as an online monitoring tool. this is why i dont think should rely on it (i personally have a habit of always setting the module/action when performing long processes in pl/sql and it overrides the existing value).

when using the program keep in mind that it can also be easily manipulated by changing the executable name - it's called spoofing.

Comment: I agree in general, but as SQL*Plus and SQL Developer are well-behaved and this is apparently only to run at the start of the script I think `module` is safe in this instance. You also need to account for variations in `program`; SQL Developer always seems to say that but for SQL*Plus you might get something like `sqlplus@myhost (TNS V1-V3)`, and there might be platform variations. So some parsing might be necessary, depending on what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, @haki, but I'm in an environment where V$SESSION is only open to admins.