# Use oracle SET values in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I was requested to set some environment parameters to migration files. However, such parameters as `SQLBLANKLINES` for instance, are only valid in sqlplus, other tools (e.g. Flyway) would be broken by its usage. Same is for `autocommit`.

Is there any way to perform following:

```
declare
   v1 varchar2(60)
begin
   v1 := SHOW SQLBLANKLINES
   if (v1 is not empty) then
      SET SQLBLANKLINES ON
   end if;
end;
/
```

Or somehow query environment for available parameters to set?

Or somehow determine that exactly sqlplus is being used?

I'm aware of `SHOW` and `SET` commands, but I don't know how to place their results to variable and call `SET` inside PL/SQL.

Oracle is 11g.

Comment: These things should be set in the client environment before running your migration files, if you don't know which client will be used. That's something for the installation instructions to specify if necessary. But no, you can't see client settings or run client commands from a PL/SQL block.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference `SQL*Plus` commands in PL/SQL, as PL/SQL doesn't recognise them. Moreover, you can't use conditional statements directly in a `SQL*Plus` script, so you have to get a bit creative. You can, however, have a script that creates and runs another script, which you can use to inject conditional statements.

For example, this is a script that I use to either let my release script continue or not (it exits `SQL*Plus`):

continue_or_exit.sql:

```
prompt Do you want to continue script execution? 

accept yn prompt 'Y / N :  ';
set termout off;
set verify off;
set heading off;
set pause off;
set echo off;
column aaaa newline;

spool continue_or_exit_output.sql

select decode(upper('&&yn'), 'Y', 'prompt Executing ...',
                                  'prompt Stopped'
              ),
       decode(upper('&&yn'), 'Y', '', 'accept return_key prompt ''Press <Return>''') aaaa,
       decode(upper('&&yn'), 'Y', '', 'exit') aaaa
from dual;

spool off;
set termout on;

@continue_or_exit_output.sql

set termout on;
set verify on;
set heading on;
```

You ought to be able to amend that for your case to decide whether to print out the relevant SQL*plus commands or not.

Comment: Looks nice, but this script is interactive, but I'd like to run it both manually and automated via Flyway

Comment: you don't have to define the variable interactively; you can pass that in as part of the script when you call it. eg. `@your_release_scripts your_param_value`, and then reference it via `&&1`. That way, you can define it at call time, which hopefully you can do in Flyway?

Comment: actually, flyway simply takes list of files with certain prefixes and execute them one by one.

Comment: Then perhaps you could create wrapper scripts that simply call the relevant script with the correct parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call SQL*Plus, or any client, commands from within PL/SQL. It is executed entirely on the server. You can tell [which client is being used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16598574/266304), at least if the client is well-behaved, but that doesn't really help you as you still can't use that information to control which client commands are issued.

The simplest approach may be to write a core script with the migration commands, and then a wrapper script for specific clients; so if you had `core_migration.sql` you could have another script called `sqlplus_migration.sql` that just did:

```
SET SQLBLANKLINES ON
-- any other SQL*Plus-specific set-up you want
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET LINESIZE 200
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE UNLIMITED
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE
-- etc.
-- Run core migration script
@core_migration
exit 0;
```

SQL*Plus needs to be able to find the core script though, so it might be better/necessary to pass the full path to that with a [substitution variable](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#CACIFHGB):

```
...
SET DEFINE ON
-- Run core migration script passed via command line
@&&1
exit 0;
```

... then call it as:

```
sqlplus -s -l usr/pwd @sqlplus_migration /path/to/core_migration.sql
```

(I don't like putting the credentials on the command line; your script could prompt for them instead but you suggested you wanted it to be non-interactive).

I'm not familiar with Flyway - it may just want to call the core script with no extra steps.

Comment: That link on clients you gave is cool. Can I execute sql file from PL/SQL?

Comment: @ka2m - no, you can't execute a file, the PL/SQL block is executed on the server and can't see the client's files or run SQL\*Plus commands (like @ or start). You could read the file with utl_file, extracts the statements, run them - but only if the file is on the server, and it's not simple even then...